# How to send a ics and know by callback answer in c#?

Tags: c#, outlook

For now I have this part, but I don't know which option the user selected.

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//ABC Company//Outlook MIMEDIR//EN");
str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");

str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", startTime1));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", endTime1));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("LOCATION: {0}", "Location"));

str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", mail.Body));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", mail.Body));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", mail.Subject));

str.AppendLine("STATUS:CONFIRMED");
str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
str.AppendLine("ACTION:Accept");
str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
str.AppendLine("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:BUSY");
str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");

str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", mail.From.Address));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", mail.To[0].DisplayName, mail.To[0].Address));

str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
ct.Parameters.Add("name", "meeting.ics");
AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), ct);
mail.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
```

Comment: You need to be much more clear as the problem you are facing. I can see you are creating an iCalendar format feed, but you seem to be asking "how do I know if the user accepts the invitation" ?

Comment: yes. That's my problem. I need to know if user accept or reject

Comment: You can't. The user might mail you baco n hte Organizer mail address, but they might not. If they did it would generate a structured email back to the organizer which youd have to read from that mail box.